# My phone is dead in my house how do I find it

Tags: applications

I had it in my bedroom and then got up for food and it disappears in the morning I ask everyone but they have not seen it or touched it not that they now of.

Comment: lol.. is this a serious question? How do you find anything you lost... look for it.

Comment: Ask your mum. Moms know about everything in the house.

Comment: @GokulNC: wish I could upvote your comment a million times :)

Comment: That is seems to be a question for Life Hacks Community

Answer (score 1):

When the phone battery is dead, there is no app or Android system that's going to help you find it, unless prior to losing it you have installed an app that collects and saves the location of your phone. In that case, use the app instructions on how to check the last possible location of the phone.

You can also have a look at your Google maps [timeline](https://www.google.com/maps/timeline?pb). unless you have disabled this feature, it collects all of your locations and travels. It could be useful in a case where you're not sure which house You've left your phone at, I'm not sure that it's going to be too helpful in telling which bed your phone is under.

Keep looking. Don't give up. Remember, it might be in the least expected of places.